# AMP HTML | Linked dropdown - more than one link / dependency

Tags: amp-html

Has someone experienced with more than one dependency in AMP, as shown in this tutorial for Linked dropdown?
https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/interactivity-dynamic-content/linked_dropdowns/

I am using a filter based on this tutorial - to filter **Model** for a vehicle, with a foreign key to **Make** - brand of vehicle.
I am wondering now, that I should add also another filter as first - a **Vehicle Type** (Automobile, Motorcycle, Boat, Jet Ski, ...)

So now I am serving to **amp-list** this JSON in *src*:

```
{
    "vehicles": [
        {
            "name": "Audi",
            "model_set": [
                "A8",
                "Q7"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "BMW",
            "model_set": [
                "M2",
                "5 Series",
                "3 Series",
                "M5",
                "X1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Mercury",
            "model_set": [
                "Milan",
                "Mountainer"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Yamaha",
            "model_set": [
                "All Other"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Has AMP capability, to handle another one dropdown - it will be first now, with **Vehicle Type**?

So it will be Vehicle Type -> Make -> Model

Thank you!

Comment: good examples on the AMP site such as: https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/interactivity-dynamic-content/linked_dropdowns/?referrer=ampbyexample.com

Comment: Yes, that is the same site, which link is in my question. There is only one dependency, but I am not sure if AMP can handle more linked dropdowns.

Comment: try this one: https://dev.optfirst.org/chattanoogaautosquare/inventory.html

Comment: This page fails to load JSON data

Comment: yes i see that `carInfo.json` is not active. however, i've used this template before and it works. it is a 3-level selector where each selection narrows the previously selected set. i have a local version with transmission, make, exterior color, and interior color (4 selectors). my local version works.

Comment: here's another one: https://capellaamp.herokuapp.com/

Comment: It seems, that it is working well, thanks a lot!